# Changing Hilbert-style axioms

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

Consider the following system for Hilbert-style deduction:
**Axioms:**

1. $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$
2. $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$
3. $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A\land B)) $
4. $A \land B \rightarrow  A$
5. $A \land B \rightarrow  B$
6. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow((C \rightarrow  B)\rightarrow(A\lor C   \rightarrow B))$
7. $A \rightarrow A\lor B$
8. $B \rightarrow A\lor B$
9. $\neg \neg A \rightarrow A$
10. $\neg A \leftrightarrow (A \rightarrow \bot)$
11. $\forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(t)$ where $t$ is free for $x$ in $A(x)$
12. $ \forall x(A \rightarrow B(x)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow \forall x B(x))$
    where $x$ is not a free variable of $A$
13. $A(t) \rightarrow \exists x A(x)$ where $t$ is free for $x$ in $A(x)$
14. $\forall x (A(x)\rightarrow B) \rightarrow(\exists x A(x) \rightarrow B)$ where $x$ is not a free variable of $B$ **(I)**

**Rules of inference:**

1. $\dfrac {A \qquad A \rightarrow B} B$
2. $\dfrac {A(x)}{\forall x A(x)}$  where $x$ is not free in the formulas used to deduce $A(x)$

$A \leftrightarrow B$ is an abbreviation for $(A \rightarrow B) \land (B \rightarrow A)$.
I can prove **(I)** semantically. This is a complete system, so one expects removing it will damage the system, since then there will be valid formulas not provable in the remaining system, leaving it incomplete, unless **(I)** was redundant in the original system.
However, I was curious with the difference the axiom has with this one:

$\forall x (A(x)\rightarrow B) \rightarrow(\forall x A(x) \rightarrow B)$ where $x$ is not a free variable of $B$. **(II)**

I'll try to explain what I think of their difference. I'll translate **(I)** and **(II)** to a small example in propositional logic, using the fact that $\forall$ behaves like $\land$ and $\exists$ like $\lor$:
**(I)'**: $(A_1\rightarrow B) \land (A_2 \rightarrow B)\rightarrow (A_1 \lor A_2\rightarrow B)$
**(II)'**: $(A_1\rightarrow B) \land (A_2 \rightarrow B)\rightarrow (A_1 \land A_2\rightarrow B)$

Using the fact that $A_1 \rightarrow B$ is equivalent to  $\neg A_1 \lor B$ the LHS of **(I)'** is equivalent to $(\neg A_1 \land \neg A_2)\lor B$ which is $\neg (A_1\lor A_2)\lor B$ which is RHS. But the similar argument does  **not**  hold for **(II)'**, meaning the implication in **(I)'** can be reversed, but not in **(II)'**. Does this actually mean **(I)'** is a "stronger" formula?

My main question is that does replacing **(II)** with **(I)** damage the Hilbert system? By damaging I mean will then there exist some formula so that the original system could prove it but the new system cannot? I think if we can somehow show that having **(I)** as an axiom we can derive **(II)** in the system, but not vice-versa, which means the original system is stronger. But how can we show something is **not**  derivable?

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question if you don't tell us what the other axioms of your system are (e.g., by giving a reference). That said, it would be surprising if replacing (I) with the much weaker (II) would result in a complete system unless (I) was redundant in the original system.

Comment: "However since this is a axiom in Hilbert system, one expects removing it will damage the system" ... I thought you said that you came up with this, not Hilbert.

Comment: @RobArthan I added all the axioms, sorry for ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that **(II)** is redundant since it's a theorem of the system (without using **(I)**). Here's a proof:

1. $\big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \qquad Ax1$
2. $\bigg( \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \rightarrow \Bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \bigg( \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \Bigg) \qquad Ax1$
3. $\forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \bigg( \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \qquad Ru1(1,2)$
4. $\Bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \bigg( \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \Bigg) \rightarrow \Bigg( \bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \bigg) \rightarrow \bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \Bigg) \qquad Ax2$
5. $\bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \bigg) \rightarrow \bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \qquad Ru1(3,4)$
6. $\forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \qquad Ax11$
7. $\forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \qquad Ru1(6,5)$
8. $\Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \Big( \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(x) \big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \qquad Ax2$
9. $\bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \Big( \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(x) \big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \rightarrow \Bigg( \bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(x) \big) \bigg) \rightarrow \bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \bigg) \Bigg) \qquad Ax2$
10. $\bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(x) \big) \bigg) \rightarrow \bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \bigg) \qquad Ru1(8,9)$
11. $\forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(x) \qquad Ax11$
12. $\big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(x) \big) \rightarrow \bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(x) \big) \bigg) \qquad Ax1$
13. $\Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(x) \big) \qquad Ru1(11,12)$
14. $\Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \qquad Ru1(13,10)$
15. $\bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \bigg) \rightarrow \Bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \bigg) \Bigg) \qquad Ax1$
16. $\forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \bigg) \qquad Ru1(14,15)$
17. $\Bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \bigg( \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \bigg) \Bigg) \rightarrow \Bigg( \bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \Bigg) \qquad Ax2$
18. $\bigg( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \bigg) \rightarrow \Big( \forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \Big) \quad Ru1(16,17)$
19. $\forall x \big( A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \rightarrow \big( \forall x A(x) \rightarrow B \big) \qquad Ru1(7,18)$

Now, the question is wether we can deduce **(I)** from the other axioms or not. If it is a theorem, you should give a proof in the system, but if it's not a theorem (as I believe so), the problem is not quite easy! To show that **(I)** is not a theorem, you can have model-theoretic approaches and proof-theoretic approaches.

In a model-theoretic approach, you may introduce a new semantics for which your deduction system (without **(I)**) is sound but there's a counter-model for **(I)**. Note that for the standard semantics we have the soundness theorem, but **(I)** is also valid; so the standard semantics doesn't work.

In a proof-theoretic approach, you may find some structural properties of your deduction system which shows that every theorem has a special property, which **(I)** doesn't have. Usually, we don't have this kind of structural properties for Hilbert-style systems. So you may find a natural deduction system, a tableau system or a Gentzen-style system which is equivalent to your system (without **(I)**) and try to prove theorems like normalization or cut-elimination.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the difference is exactly that the second statement is weaker than the first.

$$\begin{array}{l}\forall x (A(x)\to B) ~\to~ (\exists x~A(x) ~\to~ B)\\(\exists x~A(x) ~\to~ B) ~\to~ (\forall x~A(x)~\to~B)\\\hline \forall x(A(x)~\to~B)~\to~(\forall x~A(x)~\to~B) \end{array}$$

Or in your tiny universe:
$$\begin{array}{l}((A_1\to B)\wedge (A_2\to B)) ~\to~ ((A_1\vee A_2)\to B)
\\ ((A_1\vee A_2)~\to~ B)~\to~ (A_1\wedge A_2)~\to~B)\\\hline ((A_1\to B)\wedge (A_2\to B)) ~\to~ (A_1\wedge A_2)~\to~B)\end{array}$$

Comment: To show that it is a weaker statement we should also show that from II we cannot derive I. How is that possible?